# combine plain JavaScript and jQuery together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a slight problem. I've got a page layout with a left column and a right column. I want to make the columns equal, so I've been using some javascript which equals them out quite nicely. However within the right column, I have a div which I would like to hide onload, and toggle when pressed. I'm using jquery to acheive this with good results. The problem is the first javscript is fixing the height of both the columns, if I have a height fixed that is not as deep then when the user toggles to view content, the content floats above the bottom line of both columns. Hope that makes sense.

I was thinking if I convert everything to jquery, I might have a fighting chance of passing the size of the height of the right container before it is hidden and then adding the height of the column right if its too small and then levelling both columns out.

This is quite difficult to explain, but hopefully someone out there undertands what I am trying to acheive.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var contact_height = $("#ContentBlock").height();

        $("#ContentBlock").hide();

        $(".contact-us").click(function () {

            if ($('#ContentBlock').is(":hidden")) {
                $('#arrowopenclose').removeClass("panelCollapsed");
                $('#arrowopenclose').addClass("panelExpanded");
            } else {
                $('#arrowopenclose').removeClass("panelExpanded");
                $('#arrowopenclose').addClass("panelCollapsed");
            }

            $("#ContentBlock").slideToggle('fast');
            return false;
        });

    })
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
function fixHeight(one, two) {
    if (document.getElementById(one)) {
        var lh = document.getElementById(one).offsetHeight + 15;

        //figure out how tall rh is and add contact_height + 15 if the space is smaller then contact_height
        var rh = document.getElementById(two).offsetHeight;
        var nh = Math.max(lh, rh);
        document.getElementById(one).style.height = nh + "px";
        document.getElementById(two).style.height = nh + "px";
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    fixHeight('rightcolumn', 'content-container');
}
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript. I don't think re-writing your code will make any difference at all if it keeps doing essentially the same thing anyway.

Comment: why not just do this with CSS, float both columns, and put them in a container `<div>` with `overflow:auto`, maybe `height:100%` for the two columns, I think that should do what you want without getting any javascript or jquery involved

Comment: For the downvoters: the question is well-formed, but as experienced JS developers we just happen to think it's a bit "silly" (per Pointy's comment). A fiddle would help but isn't a requirement. Not sure why people are always so hot to downvote a question just because they think it's silly.

Comment: @JK36 if you're not worried about IE6 and below, I would change `document.getElementById(one).style.height = nh + "px";` to `$('#'+one).css('min-height', nh+"px");`. This way, the min-height is set, and it will expand larger as content is displayed inside. This assumes that the content inside of it is not `position:absolute/fixed/static`.

Comment: Thanks Guys for your responses, I've found a half baked solution here http://www.cssnewbie.com/equal-height-columns-with-jquery/ coupled with Daniel Allen Langdon suggestion below works

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for the backup with the down voters, still very new to all this and the amount of info out there on the web can be quite confusing for someone like me. Will experiment with css when I get a moment as suggested Rodolfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken Rodolfo's advice and recreated equal sized columns using pure css. Thanks to all that replied.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, jQuery is a JavaScript code library.  So jQuery code is JavaScript code.

If I understand your problem correctly, you're saying that you wrote some code in JavaScript (not using jQuery) that would align two columns.  You call the function `fixHeight`.

You also have something that the user can click on that causes an anonymous function to execute which expands and collapses a panel on the screen.  However, when that function executes, the two columns are no longer lined up as they were with `fixHeight`.

I propose to you that the solution may be to call `fixHeight` from within your anonymous function, like this:

```
    $(".contact-us").click(function () {

        if ($('#ContentBlock').is(":hidden")) {
            $('#arrowopenclose').removeClass("panelCollapsed");
            $('#arrowopenclose').addClass("panelExpanded");
        } else {
            $('#arrowopenclose').removeClass("panelExpanded");
            $('#arrowopenclose').addClass("panelCollapsed");
        }

        $("#ContentBlock").slideToggle('fast');

        fixHeight(one, two);

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the suggestion, almost worked but not quite. However you certainly put me on the right path, I need to use slide toggle with a callback as fixHeight was not working without it.